# Grub seems to don't load its config from grub.cfg

Tags: grub2, opensuse

I have a computer with 3 OS installed on it :

- Blinux
- Blinux exam
- Windows 7

(Blinux is a custom version of OpenSuse that we use in my school).

I have recently restored my computer with the image file provided by my school, and updated to the last version of Blinux.

Before the update, the grub looked like this :

- Blinux 2.0 STD
- Advanced options for Blinux 2.0 STD
- Blinux 2.0 EXAM STD
- Advanced options for Blinux 2.0 STD
- Windows Boot Manager

And after the update, it changed to :

- Blinux 3.0 STD
- Advanced options for Blinux 3.0 STD
- Blinux 3.0 STD
- Advanced options for Blinux 3.0 STD
- Windows Boot Manager

So according to grub, the exam partition is gone. Actually it's still here but it is now the first option in grub, the normal Blinux is now the third.

However, the OS names in `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` are the correct ones and, in any case, trying to run `grub-install /dev/sda` to update the configuration file results in:

> WARNING! You are trying to invoke the unsupported grub-install script
>   with a parameter. To really do this, call grub-install.unsupported.
>   You should rather call "yast2 bootloader" or create configuration
>   files appropriate for the intended target.

If I run `grub-install` without `/dev/sda` as parameter it opens YaST2 so I tried to reinstall grub from it but it didn't change anything.

If I run `grub2-install` or `grub2-install /dev/sda`the installation finishes without problem but it still doesn't change anything.

I think that grub is loading its configuration from another file but I can't manage to find it.

Any guesses?

Comment: 1) Are you sure you're using grub? Is this an EFI install? COuld you be using the EFI bootloader instead? 2) What happens if you run `update-grub` (or whatever is the SuSE equivalent)?

Comment: 1) I am sure I am using grub. I didn't really know what EFI means so I did some research and according to what I found, yes it is. About the EFI bootloader, I found something really weird, I looked into boot options and found a "Boot from EFI file" option that let me choose : 0 file when booting with the HDD that has the grub problem, 1 file when booting with a SSD that has the exact same OS conf (without grub problem + Linux Mint), and 2 files when booting with the SDD + the HDD pluged in USB. I tried a few options and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: However, it completely messed up with the grub on my SSD, I ran grub2-mkconfig and it's now normal again. 2) There is no such command, but I found an "update-bootloader" command that needs a "add", "refresh", "remove" or "reinit" parameter, I tried with refresh and nothing changed.

Comment: Sorry for the triple response, but I have something new. I tried again to boot from EFI file and this time the file appeared (with only the HDD plugged in SATA so I don't know what happened the first time, anyway that was illogic...) so I chose Blinux and the OS names in the grub appeared properly ! Except that there was 2 Windows (1 : Blinux - 2 : Options for Blinux - 3 : Windows - 4 : Blinux exam - 5 : Options for Blinux exam - 6 : Windows) but it's still a progress ! So what do you think about that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem !

I don't know how and why but grub loads its config from the grub.cfg file that is on the exam partition !  It has never done that before with my previous installations. So as I can't boot on this partition out of an exam, I mounted it from Blinux and ran grub2-mkconfig -o to grub.cfg file that is on the exam partition. I now have both Blinux and Blinux exam partitions showing in grub, but Windows shows up twice. As this is another problem I considerer my problem solved and I will search a solution to this new problem !